# Resolve from IoC container based on enum value

Tags: c#, ioc-container, autofac, protobuf-net

**Problem**

I have a protobuf message definition with a `MessageType` field, which is an enum. Given an incoming protobuf message, I would like to resolve some `IMessageHandler`s from an IoC container based on the `MessageType`. The problem is twofold: How do I express the `MessageType` constraint when writing an `IMessageHandler`, and how do I resolve only the desired handlers from the IoC container?

I'm using Autofac but am interested in hearing solutions for any container.

**My thoughts:**

For expressing the constraint, I see two options: a property or an attribute (can't use generics because it is an enum value). I like the property because it makes it impossible to write an `IMessageHandler` without specifying the constraint, but the downside is that it has to be instantiated before you can see the property value.

In my current code, I'm using the property approach. I resolve all `IMessageHandler`s and do the filtering manually, but it seems like there should be a better way. Not that I'm too worried about performance, it just kind of smells that I'm resolving instances that don't get used.

**Update**

To make it a little more clear, here's what I'm doing now

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    MessageType TargetType { get; }

    void Handle(IMessage message);
}

public class SomeHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public MessageType TargetType
    {
        get { return MessageType.Type1;  }
    }

    public void Handle(IMessage message)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

So when I receive a protobuf message, I resolve all `IMessageHandler`s and invoke the ones whose `TargetType` matches the `MessageType` of the incoming message.

Comment: (you mention protobuf-net, but I'm not entirely clear on the use-case here - I can't visualise very strongly what the setup is, so I'm unsure how to advise)

Comment: @Marc protobuf-net is kind of ancillary to the question. I included the tag: 1) To make it clear that generics is off the table. I can't do IMessageHandler<MessageType.Type1> because the constraint is necessarily an enum value. 2) Maybe I'm asking the wrong question and there's a better way to dispatch protobuf messages based on an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that [Autofac's Keyed Services](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices) can help me out. I think I'm going to go with this approach.

1. Use an attribute to declare what `MessageType` a given `IMessageHandler` is interested in.
2. Register every `IMessageHandler` keyed to the `MessageType`
3. Use `ResolveKeyed` to get only the `IMessageHandler`s I'm interested int.

The nice thing is if someone forgets to use the attribute, we can catch it while building the container. Here's a full example. Any suggestions are most welcome!

```
class Program
{
    static IContainer container;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly)
            .AssignableTo<IMessageHandler>()
            .Keyed<IMessageHandler>(t => GetMessageType(t));

        container = builder.Build();

        InvokeHandlers(MessageType.Type1);
        InvokeHandlers(MessageType.Type2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static MessageType GetMessageType(Type type)
    {
        var att = type.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<MessageHandlerAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (att == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Somone forgot to put the MessageHandlerAttribute on an IMessageHandler!");
        }

        return att.MessageType;
    }

    static void InvokeHandlers(MessageType type)
    {
        using (var lifetime = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            // I'm impressed that Autofac knows what I mean here!
            var handlers = lifetime.ResolveKeyed<IEnumerable<IMessageHandler>>(type);
            foreach (var handler in handlers)
            {
                handler.Handle();
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum MessageType
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
}

public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void Handle();
}

public class MessageHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MessageHandlerAttribute(MessageType messageType)
    {
        MessageType = messageType;
    }

    public MessageType MessageType { get; private set; }
}

[MessageHandler(MessageType.Type1)]
public class Handler1 : IMessageHandler
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A handler for Type1");
    }
}

[MessageHandler(MessageType.Type1)]
public class Handler2 : IMessageHandler
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Another handler for Type1");
    }
}

[MessageHandler(MessageType.Type2)]
public class Handler3 : IMessageHandler
{
    public void Handle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A handler for Type2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest hiding your own solution behind the `IMessageHandlerFactory` approach that n8wrl suggests, because you otherwise end up having a dependency on the container within your application. This is the service locator pattern, which is often considered an anti-pattern. It would be very easy to build an implementation of the `IMessageHandlerFactory` that calls the `lifetime.ResolveKeyed<IMessageHandler>(type)` for you. Another tip: don't resolve `IEnumerable<IMessageHandler>`, but simply a `IMessageHandler` and let the factory return a `CompositeMessageHandler` that does the `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, you make some good points. My example is not meant to demonstrate good IoC; I'm really just interested in how an `IMessageHandler` declares which `MessageType` it's interested in, and how to use Autofac to register and resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you register a single IMessageHandler-Factory class with autofac and implement a method on that factory that takes your enum and returns the right IMessageHandler implementation.

Comment: OK, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, that moves my problem to the implementation of the factory. How would I implement the factory? Do I still have to resolve all the IMessageHandlers? I don't want to change the factory when I add a new IMessageHandler.

Comment: Hmm. Well you have to change _something_ when you add a new handler. IoC config? Factory? Some other config file or database? Maybe you could do something with app.config to map enum names to class names? I just don't know think you can burn enums into Autofac resolution.

Comment: IoC is just a fancy dictionary mapping types to implementations. You're talking about a dictionary mapping enum values to implementations. How you populate that dictionary with minimal code changes... I guess i wonder how often you will?

Comment: In my ideal solution, I don't need to change anything when adding a new handler. The IoC is already set up to scan the relevant assemblies for message handlers. I'd rather not manually maintain any mappings.